# Sorting with Comparator not working

Tags: android, sorting, comparator

I have to store and manage a volume list in the format:
"100 ml", "200 ml", "300 ml"...

I'm using the SharedPreferences with JSON to store this everytime the list is changed.

I want the list to be ordered, so 100 < 1000, but it is showing like 1000 and 2000 before 300.

Here is my comparator:

```
mVolumeComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {

            int volume1 = Integer.parseInt(s1.replace(" ml", ""));
            int volume2 = Integer.parseInt(s2.replace(" ml", ""));

            if (volume1 > volume2) {
                return 1;
            } else if (volume2 > volume1) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    };
```

And here is my get method:

```
public static ArrayList<String> getVolumesFromPreference(Context ctx) {

    if (!ctx.getSharedPreferences(KEY_SHARED_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE).contains(KEY_VOLUMES_BUNDLE)) {

        startDefaultVolumes(ctx, KEY_VOLUMES_BUNDLE);

    }

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(ctx.getSharedPreferences(KEY_SHARED_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE).getString(KEY_VOLUMES_BUNDLE, null));
        ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            lista.add(jsonArray.getString(i));
        }

        Collections.sort(lista, mVolumeComparator);

        return lista;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }


}

 private static void startDefaultVolumes(Context ctx, String key_bundle) {

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    jsonArray.put("269 ml");
    jsonArray.put("350 ml");
    jsonArray.put("473 ml");
    jsonArray.put("550 ml");
    jsonArray.put("600 ml");

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = ctx.getSharedPreferences(KEY_SHARED_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(key_bundle, jsonArray.toString());
    editor.commit();

}
```

[image: Volumes Lib]

Comment: Where does 1000 ml come from? In json array I can see only 269 - 600 and they are sorted ok

Comment: A side note, consider not storing application data in shared preferences, they are poorly suited for large amounts of data, as it will read it into ram first time you access it.

Comment: The user can add and remove volumes.
And i thought not necessary a whole DB only for these list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Integer.valueOf() method instead Integer.parceInt()

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you to store only the value "100", "1000", "300" and UNIT if you have more than unit available.

SO, you can order it just with a normal Integer comparator, and then apply the "ml" suffix at runtime

Comment: Its a good ideia. I'll think about it, it was the first ideia. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for sorting arraylist in ascending order.

```
 ArrayList<int> lista = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            lista.add(Integer.parseInt(jsonArray.getString(i)));
        }

 Collections.sort(lista , new Comparator<Integer >() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer lhs, Integer rhs) {
                return Integer.valueOf(lhs).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(rhs));
            }
        });
```